# System in the canonical ensemble in Pathria: "Statistical Mechanics"

Tags: statistical-mechanics

[image]

3.2 topic of canonical ensemble page 45 equation 17 to 19

What is doubly restricted sets and how do we know it is doubly restricted.

How that is equal to singly restricted sets.

And after that the role of method of residue 
It is complete chaos for me plz elaborate this.....

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (17), the sum inside brackets is restricted by two constraints: the total number of particles is $\mathcal{N}$ and the total energy is $U$. All this seems to be indicated by the prime applied to the sum (yeah, the notation is pretty bad).
It would have been better to write it
$$
G(\mathcal{N},z) = \sum_{U=0}^\infty \Bigl[ \sum_{\{n_r\}} 1_{\{\sum_k n_k=\mathcal{N}, \sum_k n_k E_k =U\}} \frac{\mathcal{N}!}{\prod_k n_k!} \prod_k \bigl(\omega_k z^{E_k}\bigr)^{n_k} \Bigr].
$$
Anyway, since $\sum_k n_k E_k =U$, one can rewrite the above as
$$
G(\mathcal{N},z) = \sum_{U=0}^\infty \Gamma(\mathcal{N}, U) z^U,
$$
where the coefficients
$$
\Gamma(\mathcal{N}, U) = \sum_{\{n_r\}} 1_{\{\sum_k n_k=\mathcal{N}, \sum_k n_k E_k =U\}} \frac{\mathcal{N}!}{\prod_k n_k!} \prod_k \omega_k^{n_k}
$$
correspond to the partition functions with constraints both on the number particles $\mathcal{N}$ and on the total energy $U$.

He then goes on by saying that one can recover these coefficients from (18) using the standard formula (19) (see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_in_complex_analysis)).

Comment: Does this answer your question or do you need additional explanations?

Comment: Yes, i understand it sir thank u very much for you efforts.